# Why are community-wallets able to outperform the official solutions during the current "congestion"?

Tags: wallet, daedalus, yoroi

Can someone please explain the difference that led to some community-wallets beeing able to operate so much better during this congested period?
I have hours delay when using yoroi, but only 1-2 minutes delay when using ccvault for example.
I can not explain why the difference is so big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably have a better queuing system for transactions when the tx cannot be submitted to the mempool immediately. It also could be yoroi receives a lot more transactions in general. There's a number of variables that could lead to a system having faster or slower adoption of transactions.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up Sam :-)